# How can I install this excel add-in from sharepoint?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I have an excel add-in that I want to store in a shared sharepoint folder so that the end user's workbook downloads the latest version add-in when they open their workbook. My problem lies in how to get the path to the file. I'm not including all of the code because I believe only this part is relevant.

Sample made up source file path to sharepoint:
  https://groups.blah.com/:x:/r/Sites/mydept/shared%20Documents/Test/MyAddIn.xlam?csf=1&web=1&e=5vYskg

I tried a couple of options

1. Try to copy the file to the user AddIns folder:
   **FileCopy sourcePath, Application.UserLibraryPath & "MyAddIn.xlam"**
   Results in "Bad file name or number" error
2. Use the Add method:
   **Addins.Add sourcePath, False**
   Results in "Add method of AddIns class failed" error

I'm not too knowledgeable on add-ins and sharepoint. We have sharepoint and onedrive to use as our network options.

Also, a secondary question is once an add-in is installed, is it best practice to uninstall it when the user closes their workbook? I ask because I only want the add-in to run on a particular workbook and not whenever any workbook is opened. My best guess was to uninstall on workbook close

Comment: Hi, the edit was the answer. I'll hit the checkmark below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by storing the add-in on the sharepoint site and sending users a link to the file on the sharepoint site that they can connect to their onedrive by clicking the "add shortcut to onedrive."  Once added, I can get the path to their onedrive my documents folder that has the shared link and install from there

Answer (score 0):

The link to the file needs to be cleaned up. It looks like it has been generated through the SharePoint GUI, using a Share link. These contain all kinds of rubbish that only SharePoint understands. The clean link to just the file can be constructed from the above. Remove the `:x/:r/` and anything after the `.xlam` extension.

original link:
`https://groups.blah.com/:x:/r/Sites/mydept/shared%20Documents/Test/MyAddIn.xlam?csf=1&web=1&e=5vYskg`

clean link:
`https://groups.blah.com/Sites/mydept/shared%20Documents/Test/MyAddIn.xlam`

For your other question, please start a new question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same errors when removing the extra bits